# "make" error when building nana for c++

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, nana

I've been trying to install the nana library for c++. I've used these guides:
https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Installation

https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Install-and-use-nana-with-mingw---step-by-step

I got stuck on the part that says "Create a static linkage library solution within a IDE/build system you use, and add all the files which are placed in NanaPath/source and in all its sub directories to the project. Then compile the solution and you will get a static linkage file NanaStatic in a path similar to NanaPath/build/bin/IDEName."

I downloaded MinGW, git, and cmake like it said. I opened up the bat file, ran the "git clone" with the link, ran

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

It did it's thing and finished successfully. Then I tried running "make" and it got to 6% when this showed up:

```
In file included from C:/Users/.../nana/verbose_prepocessor.hpp:99:0,
from C:\Users\...\nana\source\deploy.cpp:242:C/Users/.../nana/include/filesystem/filesystem.hpp:71:39: fatal error: experimental/filesystem: No such file or directory
#    include<experimental/filesystem>
                                     ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\nana.dir\build.make:163: CMakeFiles/nana.dir/source/deploy.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/nana.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:129: all] Error 2
```

I tried using a different source of the code (git and sourceforge) and that didn't make a difference. I tried using the GUI cmake, but I had other errors with that not recognizing MinGW. I looked around for answers online, but they mostly led back to the guides I was using. I checked my GCC and G++ version with gcc/g++ --version, and they're both 6.3.0.

I'll take any suggestions/advice, thanks!

Comment: What compiler are you using? Edit: sorry, I must still be asleep...

Comment: g++ downloaded from https://nuwen.net/mingw.html I tried the suggested http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/ but couldn't find "open_distro_window.bat"

Comment: Try running cmake with `-DNANA_CMAKE_NANA_FILESYSTEM_FORCE=True` and see wether it helps.

Comment: Almost there! That worked and now nana is successfully built. Now I'm trying to incorporate everything into Eclipse. I'm a bit confused at the language of the guide but I put \nana\include (original code) in the Includes tab, NANA_MINGW and NANA_UNICODE under symbols, \Program Files (x86)\nana (the place where it built) in the library path, and \Program Files (x86)\nana\lib\libnana.a in the libraries (can't find libgdi32.a, libcomdlg32.a, and libz.a). There's a fatal error with experimental/filesystem again.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Eclipse, so I cant help with that. But I will try to help with nana:

Originaly there was no `std::filesystem` and nana offered one JinHao invented. With the apparition of `std::experimental::filsystem` candidate, an experimental filesystem in the `sdt::` c++ library of some versions of some compilers we adapted the nana filesystem to be a partial implementation of that. Then nana try to configure itself to use the provided `std::` (or Boost) implementation or if it is not there then `nana::filesystem`. It seems like MinGW have problems with filesystem, I'm not sure about that but here you can read: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/2292

Please try to undertstand what is going on in your case an let us know about. We will then try to fix the configuration of nana to work even in that situation. 
You can always simply choise to  (force) use the nana implementation. Just please compile both the nana library and your project with all the same options, including what filesytem you use. For example adding `-DNANA_CMAKE_NANA_FILESYSTEM_FORCE=True` to your cmake or define `NANA_FILESYSTEM_FORCE` in your built system (or IDE).

Comment: Ahh... and we need help to improve and actualice the documentation :-)

Comment: I attempted using cygwin and ran cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"

Comment: (Sorry, new here and kept hitting enter too early when I wanted to break a line) I tried using cygwin, installed nana via git, and ran cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles". Then I ran "make" and got this long error (next comment)

Comment: In file included from /home/Cindy/nana/source/detail/platform_spec_selector.hpp:20:0,
                 from /home/Cindy/nana/source/deploy.cpp:24:
/home/Cindy/nana/source/detail/posix/platform_spec.hpp:27:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/Xlib.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/nana.dir/build.make:159: CMakeFiles/nana.dir/source/deploy.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/nana.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2

Comment: umhh... X11, in windows? Can you use some cmake  Generator for windows for Eclipse?

Comment: try `Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/generator/Eclipse%20CDT4.html

Comment: In MinGW I ran 'cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"  and make came with the exact same error as above with <experimental/filesystem>. If it helps, I'm on windows 8.1

Comment: Same thing happened with Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles

Comment: for cygwin: Have you installed https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html#setup-cygwin-x-installing ?

Comment: I installed xorg-server, xinit, xorg-docs, and the dependent packages. Then I ran 'cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"' and 'make', and it still came up with the #include <X11/Xlib.h> error

Comment: I see... we will need to debug this: can you ask this at http://nanapro.org/en-us/forum/ ? There may be people that know Eclipse, cmake, MinGW, cygwin, gcc 6.e better.

Comment: I think nana get confused being in windows but using linux libraries. Still for MinWG and MinGW Makefiles forcing nana::filesystem have to work

Comment: I posted: http://nanapro.org/en-us/forum/index.php?u=/topic/156/Using%20nana%20in%20Eclipse:%20from%20stackoverflow

Comment: Post there by your onw, it will be better.